# THREE.JS | GLSL Downshifting polygon GLSL particles

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

There's a great experiment made by Jaume Sanchez (https://experiments.withgoogle.com/the-polygon-shredder, https://github.com/spite/polygon-shredder).

If you set scaleX = scale Y = scale Z = 1.0, you would see that each particle becomes a box. Pretty sure that it's a three square polygons looking at you.

[image]

Pretty sure that all magic is in just one vertex shader:

```
<script id="vs-particles" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

precision highp float;

attribute vec3 position;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

uniform sampler2D map;
uniform sampler2D prevMap;

uniform vec3 boxVertices[ 36 ];
uniform vec3 boxNormals[ 3 ];

uniform float width;
uniform float height;

uniform float timer;
uniform vec3 boxScale;
uniform float meshScale;

varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec4 vColor;

varying vec4 vShadowCoord;
uniform mat4 shadowV;
uniform mat4 shadowP;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

varying vec3 vLightPosition;

uniform sampler2D diffuse;

const mat4 biasMatrix = mat4(
    0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0
);

mat4 rotationMatrix(vec3 axis, float angle) {

    axis = normalize(axis);
    float s = sin(angle);
    float c = cos(angle);
    float oc = 1.0 - c;

    return mat4(oc * axis.x * axis.x + c,           oc * axis.x * axis.y - axis.z * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.x + axis.y * s,  0.0,
                oc * axis.x * axis.y + axis.z * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.y + c,           oc * axis.y * axis.z - axis.x * s,  0.0,
                oc * axis.z * axis.x - axis.y * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.z + axis.x * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.z + c,           0.0,
                0.0,                                0.0,                                0.0,                                1.0);
}

float ramp( float x ) {
    return 1. - 1. - pow( 1. - x, 4. );
}

float parabola( float x, float k ) {
    return pow( 4. * x * ( 1. - x ), k );
}

float random(vec4 seed4){
    //return fract(sin(dot(co.xy ,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
    float dot_product = dot(seed4, vec4(12.9898,78.233,45.164,94.673));
    return fract(sin(dot_product) * 43758.5453);
}

mat3 calcLookAtMatrix(vec3 origin, vec3 target, float roll) {
    vec3 rr = vec3(sin(roll), cos(roll), 0.0);
    vec3 ww = normalize(target - origin);
    vec3 uu = normalize(cross(ww, rr));
    vec3 vv = normalize(cross(uu, ww));

    return mat3(uu, vv, ww);
}

void main() {

    vec2 dimensions = vec2( width, height );

    float px = position.y;
    float vi = position.z;
    float x = mod( px, dimensions.x );
    float y = mod( floor( px / dimensions.x ), dimensions.y );
    vec2 uv = vec2( x, y ) / dimensions;

    vec4 cubePosition = texture2D( map, uv );
    vec4 prevPosition = texture2D( prevMap, uv );
    float alpha = cubePosition.a / 100.;
    float scale = .025 * parabola( 1. - alpha, 1. );
    vec3 faceNormal = boxNormals[ int( vi / 6. ) ];
    mat4 localRotation = mat4( calcLookAtMatrix( cubePosition.xyz, prevPosition.xyz, 0. ) );

    vec4 rotatedNormal = localRotation * vec4( faceNormal, 1. );
    vec3 visPosition = ( modelMatrix * ( cubePosition + rotatedNormal * scale ) ).xyz;
    float d = dot( normalize( visPosition - cameraPosition ), normalize( ( modelMatrix * rotatedNormal ).xyz ) );
    vec3 boxVertex = boxVertices[ int( vi + ( 1. - step( 0., d ) ) * 18. ) ];
    vec3 modifiedVertex = ( ( localRotation * vec4( boxVertex * scale * boxScale * meshScale, 1. ) ).xyz );
    vec3 modifiedPosition = cubePosition.xyz + modifiedVertex;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( modifiedPosition, 1.0 );
    vPosition = modifiedPosition;

    vShadowCoord = biasMatrix * shadowP * shadowV * modelMatrix * vec4( modifiedPosition, 1. );

    vColor = texture2D( diffuse, uv );
    vLightPosition = lightPosition;

}

</script>
```

I'm trying to downshift this vertex shader, so you would have just one sprite looking at you.

[image]

https://bl.ocks.org/vkuchinov/0942e561a993ce91d789299b44adfee0

Pretty sure that it's something with boxVertices and boxNormals uniforms, I need somehow to do away from them. As well, I don't understand why there are so many positions attributes, multipled by 18:

```
var positionsLength = curlNoiseModel.width * curlNoiseModel.height * 3 * 18;
var positions = new Float32Array( positionsLength );

var p = 0;

for( var j = 0; j < positionsLength; j += 3 ) {

    positions[ j ] = p
    positions[ j + 1 ] = Math.floor( p / 18 )
    positions[ j + 2 ] = p % 18
    p++;

}
```

Does anyone has any idea how to downshift shaders?

```js
var T=THREE;var config={camera:new T.Vector3(0,0,-5),background:"#1D3557",colors:["#457B9D","#A8DADC","#F1FAEE","#E63946"]};var scale=0,nScale=1;var params={type:2,spread:4,factor:0.5,evolution:0.5,rotation:0.5,radius:2,pulsate:false,scaleX:1,scaleY:1,scaleZ:1,scale:1};var t=new T.Clock();var m=new T.Matrix4();var v=new T.Vector3();var nOffset=new T.Vector3(0,0,0);var tmpVector=new T.Vector3();var isMobile=false;var current="intro",rndr,scene,camera,controls,CNM,particles,particleGLSL,shadowParticleGLSL,sCamera,sBuffer,sBufferSize=512;var diffuseData,diffuseTexture,lt,en;function CurlNoise(e,c,g){this.width=c;this.height=g;this.rndr=e;this.targetPos=0;this.data=new Float32Array(this.width*this.height*4);var a=1;for(var f=0,d=this.width*this.height;f<d;f++){var h=Math.random()*2*Math.PI;var k=Math.random()*2-1;var b=Math.acos(k);a=0.85+0.15*Math.random();this.data[f*4]=a*Math.sin(b)*Math.cos(h);this.data[f*4+1]=a*Math.sin(b)*Math.sin(h);this.data[f*4+2]=a*Math.cos(b);this.data[f*4+3]=Math.random()*100}var j=isMobile?T.HalfFloatType:T.FloatType;this.texture=new T.DataTexture(this.data,this.width,this.height,T.RGBAFormat,T.FloatType);this.texture.minFilter=T.NearestFilter;this.texture.magFilter=T.NearestFilter;this.texture.needsUpdate=true;this.rtTexturePos=new T.WebGLRenderTarget(this.width,this.height,{wrapS:T.ClampToEdgeWrapping,wrapT:T.ClampToEdgeWrapping,minFilter:T.NearestFilter,magFilter:T.NearestFilter,format:T.RGBAFormat,type:j,stencilBuffer:false,depthBuffer:false,generateMipmaps:false});this.targets=[this.rtTexturePos,this.rtTexturePos.clone()];this.simulationShader=new T.ShaderMaterial({uniforms:{active:{type:"f",value:1},width:{type:"f",value:this.width},height:{type:"f",value:this.height},oPositions:{type:"t",value:this.texture},tPositions:{type:"t",value:null},timer:{type:"f",value:0},delta:{type:"f",value:0},speed:{type:"f",value:0.5},reset:{type:"f",value:0},offset:{type:"v3",value:new T.Vector3(0,0,0)},genScale:{type:"f",value:1},factor:{type:"f",value:0.5},evolution:{type:"f",value:0.5},inverseModelViewMatrix:{type:"m4",value:new T.Matrix4()},radius:{type:"f",value:2}},vertexShader:document.getElementById("texture_vertex_simulation_shader").textContent,fragmentShader:document.getElementById("texture_fragment_simulation_shader").textContent,side:T.DoubleSide});this.simulationShader.uniforms.tPositions.value=this.texture;this.rtScene=new T.Scene();this.rtCamera=new T.OrthographicCamera(-this.width/2,this.width/2,-this.height/2,this.height/2,-500,1000);this.rtQuad=new T.Mesh(new T.PlaneBufferGeometry(this.width,this.height),this.simulationShader);this.rtScene.add(this.rtQuad);this.rndr.setRenderTarget(this.rtTexturePos);this.rndr.render(this.rtScene,this.rtCamera);this.rndr.setRenderTarget(null);this.plane=new T.Mesh(new T.PlaneGeometry(64,64),new T.MeshBasicMaterial({map:this.rtTexturePos.texture,side:T.DoubleSide}))}CurlNoise.prototype.render=function(b,a){this.simulationShader.uniforms.timer.value=b;this.simulationShader.uniforms.delta.value=a;this.simulationShader.uniforms.tPositions.value=this.targets[this.targetPos].texture;this.targetPos=1-this.targetPos;this.rndr.setRenderTarget(this.targets[this.targetPos]);this.rndr.render(this.rtScene,this.rtCamera);this.rndr.setRenderTarget(null)};inits();function inits(){rndr=new T.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});rndr.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);rndr.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);document.body.appendChild(rndr.domElement);scene=new T.Scene();scene.background=new T.Color(config.background);camera=new T.PerspectiveCamera(35,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,0.1,1000);camera.position.set(config.camera.x,config.camera.y,config.camera.z);controls=new T.OrbitControls(camera,rndr.domElement);controls.enabled=false;var e=15;sCamera=new T.OrthographicCamera(-e,e,e,-e,0.1,20);sCamera.position.set(10,4,10);sCamera.lookAt(scene.position);sBuffer=new T.WebGLRenderTarget(sBufferSize,sBufferSize,{wrapS:T.ClampToEdgeWrapping,wrapT:T.ClampToEdgeWrapping,minFilter:isMobile.any?T.NearestFilter:T.LinearMipMapLinear,magFilter:isMobile.any?T.NearestFilter:T.LinearFilter,format:T.RGBAFormat});var f=new T.AmbientLight(16777215);scene.add(f);lt=new T.Mesh(new T.CylinderGeometry(5,6,1,36),new T.MeshBasicMaterial({color:16777215}));lt.position.copy(sCamera.position);lt.lookAt(scene.position);lt.rotation.y+=Math.PI/2;lt.rotation.z+=Math.PI/2;en=new T.Mesh(new T.CylinderGeometry(5.1,6.1,0.9,36),new T.MeshBasicMaterial({color:1052688}));en.position.copy(sCamera.position);en.lookAt(scene.position);en.rotation.y+=Math.PI/2;en.rotation.z+=Math.PI/2;CNM=new CurlNoise(rndr,128,128);var h=new T.BufferGeometry();var d=CNM.width*CNM.height*3*18;var a=new Float32Array(d);var g=0;for(var b=0;b<d;b+=3){a[b]=g;a[b+1]=Math.floor(g/18);a[b+2]=g%18;g++}h.addAttribute("position",new T.BufferAttribute(a,3));diffuseData=new Uint8Array(CNM.width*CNM.height*4);for(var b=0;b<CNM.width*CNM.height*4;b+=4){var i=new T.Color(interpolateColors(b/4,CNM.width*CNM.height));diffuseData[b+0]=i.r*255;diffuseData[b+1]=i.g*255;diffuseData[b+2]=i.b*255}diffuseTexture=new T.DataTexture(diffuseData,CNM.width,CNM.height,T.RGBAFormat);diffuseTexture.minFilter=T.NearestFilter;diffuseTexture.magFilter=T.NearestFilter;diffuseTexture.needsUpdate=true;particleGLSL=new T.ShaderMaterial({uniforms:{map:{type:"t",value:CNM.rtTexturePos.texture},prevMap:{type:"t",value:CNM.rtTexturePos.texture},diffuse:{type:"t",value:diffuseTexture},width:{type:"f",value:CNM.width},height:{type:"f",value:CNM.height},dimensions:{type:"v2",value:new T.Vector2(sBufferSize,sBufferSize)},timer:{type:"f",value:0},spread:{type:"f",value:4},boxScale:{type:"v3",value:new T.Vector3()},meshScale:{type:"f",value:1},depthTexture:{type:"t",value:sBuffer.texture},shadowV:{type:"m4",value:new T.Matrix4()},shadowP:{type:"m4",value:new T.Matrix4()},resolution:{type:"v2",value:new T.Vector2(sBufferSize,sBufferSize)},ltPosition:{type:"v3",value:new T.Vector3()},projector:{type:"t",value:null},boxVertices:{type:"3fv",value:[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1]},boxNormals:{type:"3fv",value:[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0]}},vertexShader:document.getElementById("vs-particles").textContent,fragmentShader:document.getElementById("fs-particles").textContent,side:T.DoubleSide,flatShading:T.FlatShading,transparent:true});shadowParticleGLSL=new T.ShaderMaterial({uniforms:{map:{type:"t",value:CNM.rtTexturePos.texture},prevMap:{type:"t",value:CNM.rtTexturePos.texture},width:{type:"f",value:CNM.width},height:{type:"f",value:CNM.height},timer:{type:"f",value:0},boxScale:{type:"v3",value:new T.Vector3()},meshScale:{type:"f",value:1},shadowV:{type:"m4",value:new T.Matrix4()},shadowP:{type:"m4",value:new T.Matrix4()},resolution:{type:"v2",value:new T.Vector2(sBufferSize,sBufferSize)},ltPosition:{type:"v3",value:new T.Vector3()},boxVertices:{type:"3fv",value:[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1]},boxNormals:{type:"3fv",value:[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,-1,0]}},vertexShader:document.getElementById("vs-particles").textContent,fragmentShader:document.getElementById("fs-particles-shadow").textContent,side:T.DoubleSide,transparent:true});particles=new T.Mesh(h,particleGLSL);scene.add(particles);window.addEventListener("resize",onWindowResize,false);animate()}function animate(){controls.update();scale+=(nScale-scale)*0.1;var c=t.getDelta()*10;var b=t.elapsedTime;var a=3;nOffset.set(a*Math.sin(b),a*Math.cos(0.9*b),0);tmpVector.copy(nOffset);tmpVector.sub(CNM.simulationShader.uniforms.offset.value);tmpVector.multiplyScalar(0.1);CNM.simulationShader.uniforms.offset.value.add(tmpVector);CNM.simulationShader.uniforms.factor.value=params.factor;CNM.simulationShader.uniforms.evolution.value=params.evolution;CNM.simulationShader.uniforms.radius.value=params.pulsate?(0.5+0.5*Math.cos(b))*params.radius:params.radius;if(CNM.simulationShader.uniforms.active.value){particles.rotation.y=params.rotation*b}m.copy(particles.matrixWorld);CNM.simulationShader.uniforms.inverseModelViewMatrix.value.getInverse(m);CNM.simulationShader.uniforms.genScale.value=scale;if(CNM.simulationShader.uniforms.active.value===1){CNM.render(b,c)}particleGLSL.uniforms.map.value=shadowParticleGLSL.uniforms.map.value=CNM.targets[CNM.targetPos].texture;particleGLSL.uniforms.prevMap.value=shadowParticleGLSL.uniforms.prevMap.value=CNM.targets[1-CNM.targetPos].texture;particleGLSL.uniforms.spread.value=params.spread;particleGLSL.uniforms.timer.value=shadowParticleGLSL.uniforms.timer.value=b;particleGLSL.uniforms.boxScale.value.set(params.scaleX,params.scaleY,params.scaleZ);shadowParticleGLSL.uniforms.boxScale.value.set(params.scaleX,params.scaleY,params.scaleZ);particleGLSL.uniforms.meshScale.value=params.scale;shadowParticleGLSL.uniforms.meshScale.value=params.scale;rndr.setClearColor(0);particles.material=shadowParticleGLSL;lt.material.visible=false;en.material.visible=false;rndr.setRenderTarget(sBuffer);rndr.render(scene,sCamera);rndr.setRenderTarget(null);lt.material.visible=true;en.material.visible=true;tmpVector.copy(scene.position);tmpVector.sub(sCamera.position);tmpVector.normalize();m.makeRotationY(-particles.rotation.y);v.copy(sCamera.position);v.applyMatrix4(m);particleGLSL.uniforms.shadowP.value.copy(sCamera.projectionMatrix);particleGLSL.uniforms.shadowV.value.copy(sCamera.matrixWorldInverse);particleGLSL.uniforms.ltPosition.value.copy(v);rndr.setClearColor(16777215);particles.material=particleGLSL;rndr.render(scene,camera);requestAnimationFrame(animate);rndr.render(scene,camera)}function onWindowResize(){camera.aspect=window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight;camera.updateProjectionMatrix();rndr.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight)}function interpolateColors(d,b){var a=remapFloat(d,0,b,0,3);var f=Math.floor(a);var e=Math.ceil(a);var c=a-f;return lerpHexColors(config.colors[f],config.colors[e],c)}function lerpHexColors(l,f,g){var i=parseInt(l.replace(/#/g,""),16),b=i>>16,j=i>>8&255,o=i&255,d=parseInt(f.replace(/#/g,""),16),n=d>>16,e=d>>8&255,h=d&255,c=b+g*(n-b),k=j+g*(e-j),a=o+g*(h-o);return"#"+((1<<24)+(c<<16)+(k<<8)+a|0).toString(16).slice(1)}function remapFloat(d,e,b,a,c){return a+(d-e)/(b-e)*(c-a)}function hexToRGB(b){var a=/^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(b);return a?{r:parseInt(a[1],16)/255,g:parseInt(a[2],16)/255,b:parseInt(a[3],16)/255}:null};
```

```css
body { margin: 0; background-color: dimgrey; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Particle Clover [PoC] tweaked version of particle-love.com by Edan Kwan</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.106.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.106.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
     
    </head>
    <body>
  
    <script id="texture_vertex_simulation_shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying vec3 vOffset;

        uniform vec3 offset;
        uniform mat4 inverseModelViewMatrix;

        void main() {

            vOffset=(inverseModelViewMatrix*vec4(offset,1.)).xyz;
            vUv=vec2(uv.x,1.0-uv.y);
            gl_Position=projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vec4(position,1.0);

        }

    </script>

    <script id="texture_fragment_simulation_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    vec3 mod289(vec3 x_) { return x_-floor(x_*(1.0/289.0))*289.0;  }

    vec4 mod289(vec4 x_) { return x_-floor(x_*(1.0/289.0))*289.0; }

    vec4 permute(vec4 x_) { return mod289(((x_*34.0)+1.0)*x_); }

    vec4 taylorInvSqrt(vec4 r_){ return 1.79284291400159-0.85373472095314*r_; }

    float snoise(vec3 v_) {

        const vec2  C=vec2(1.0/6.0,1.0/3.0) ;
        const vec4  D=vec4(0.0,0.5,1.0,2.0);

        vec3 i=floor(v_+dot(v_,C.yyy));
        vec3 x0=v_-i+dot(i,C.xxx);

        vec3 g=step(x0.yzx,x0.xyz);
        vec3 l=1.0-g;
        vec3 i1=min(g.xyz,l.zxy);
        vec3 i2=max(g.xyz,l.zxy);

        vec3 x1=x0-i1+C.xxx;
        vec3 x2=x0-i2+C.yyy;
        vec3 x3=x0-D.yyy;

        i=mod289(i);
        
        vec4 p=permute(permute(permute(
              i.z+vec4(0.0,i1.z,i2.z,1.0))
           +i.y+vec4(0.0,i1.y,i2.y,1.0))
           +i.x+vec4(0.0,i1.x,i2.x,1.0));

        float n_=0.142857142857;
        vec3  ns=n_*D.wyz-D.xzx;

        vec4 j=p-49.0*floor(p*ns.z*ns.z);

        vec4 x_=floor(j*ns.z);
        vec4 y_=floor(j-7.0*x_);

        vec4 x=x_ *ns.x+ns.yyyy;
        vec4 y=y_ *ns.x+ns.yyyy;
        vec4 h=1.0-abs(x)-abs(y);

        vec4 b0=vec4(x.xy,y.xy);
        vec4 b1=vec4(x.zw,y.zw);

        vec4 s0=floor(b0)*2.0+1.0;
        vec4 s1=floor(b1)*2.0+1.0;
        vec4 sh=-step(h,vec4(0.0));

        vec4 a0=b0.xzyw+s0.xzyw*sh.xxyy ;
        vec4 a1=b1.xzyw+s1.xzyw*sh.zzww ;

        vec3 p0=vec3(a0.xy,h.x);
        vec3 p1=vec3(a0.zw,h.y);
        vec3 p2=vec3(a1.xy,h.z);
        vec3 p3=vec3(a1.zw,h.w);

        vec4 norm=taylorInvSqrt(vec4(dot(p0,p0),dot(p1,p1),dot(p2,p2),dot(p3,p3)));
        p0 *= norm.x;
        p1 *= norm.y;
        p2 *= norm.z;
        p3 *= norm.w;

        vec4 m=max(0.6-vec4(dot(x0,x0),dot(x1,x1),dot(x2,x2),dot(x3,x3)),0.0);
        m=m*m;
        return 42.0*dot(m*m,vec4(dot(p0,x0),dot(p1,x1),dot(p2,x2),dot(p3,x3)));

    }

    vec3 snoiseVec3(vec3 x_){

        float s =snoise(vec3(x_));
        float s1=snoise(vec3(x_.y-19.1,x_.z+33.4,x_.x+47.2));
        float s2=snoise(vec3(x_.z+74.2,x_.x-124.5,x_.y+99.4));
        vec3 c=vec3(s,s1,s2);
        return c;

    }

    vec3 curlNoise(vec3 p_){

        const float e=.1;
        vec3 dx=vec3(e  ,0.0,0.0);
        vec3 dy=vec3(0.0,e  ,0.0);
        vec3 dz=vec3(0.0,0.0,e  );

        vec3 p_x0=snoiseVec3(p_-dx);
        vec3 p_x1=snoiseVec3(p_+dx);
        vec3 p_y0=snoiseVec3(p_-dy);
        vec3 p_y1=snoiseVec3(p_+dy);
        vec3 p_z0=snoiseVec3(p_-dz);
        vec3 p_z1=snoiseVec3(p_+dz);

        float x=p_y1.z-p_y0.z-p_z1.y+p_z0.y;
        float y=p_z1.x-p_z0.x-p_x1.z+p_x0.z;
        float z=p_x1.y-p_x0.y-p_y1.x+p_y0.x;

        const float divisor=1.0/(2.0*e);
        return normalize(vec3(x,y,z)*divisor);

    }

    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec3 vOffset;

    uniform float active;
    uniform sampler2D tPositions;
    uniform sampler2D oPositions;
    uniform float width;
    uniform float height;
    uniform vec3 offset;

    uniform float timer;
    uniform float delta;
    uniform float speed;
    uniform float reset;
    uniform float genScale;
    uniform float factor;
    uniform float evolution;
    uniform float radius;
    
    mat4 rotationMatrix(vec3 axis_,float angle_) {

        axis_=normalize(axis_);
        float s=sin(angle_);
        float c=cos(angle_);
        float oc=1.0-c;

        return mat4(oc*axis_.x*axis_.x+c,oc*axis_.x*axis_.y-axis_.z*s,oc*axis_.z*axis_.x+axis_.y*s,0.0,oc*axis_.x*axis_.y+axis_.z*s,oc*axis_.y*axis_.y+c,oc*axis_.y*axis_.z-axis_.x*s,0.0,oc*axis_.z*axis_.x-axis_.y*s, oc*axis_.y*axis_.z+axis_.x*s, oc*axis_.z*axis_.z+c,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
                    
    }
    
    void main() {

        vec4 c=texture2D(tPositions,vUv);
        vec3 pos=c.xyz;
        float life=c.a;

        float s=vUv.x*life/100.;
        float speedInc=1.;
        if(s > .95) speedInc=.75;
        else if(s > .9) speedInc=.85;
        else speedInc=1.;

        vec3 v=factor*speedInc*delta*speed*(curlNoise(.2*pos+factor*evolution*.1*timer));
        pos += v;
        life -= factor*1.;

        if(length(pos) < radius) {  pos=normalize(pos)*radius; }

        if(life <= 0. || reset == 1.) {

            pos=(rotationMatrix(vec3(1.,0.,0.),timer)*texture2D(oPositions,vUv)).xyz+vOffset;
            life=100.;

        }

        gl_FragColor=vec4(pos,life);

    }


    </script>

    <script id="vs-particles" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    precision highp float;

    uniform sampler2D map;
    uniform sampler2D prevMap;

    uniform vec3 boxVertices[ 36 ];
    uniform vec3 boxNormals[ 3 ];

    uniform float width;
    uniform float height;

    uniform float timer;
    uniform vec3 boxScale;
    uniform float meshScale;

    varying vec3 vPosition;
    varying vec4 vColor;

    varying vec4 vShadowCoord;
    uniform mat4 shadowV;
    uniform mat4 shadowP;
    uniform vec3 lightPosition;

    varying vec3 vLightPosition;

    uniform sampler2D diffuse;

    const mat4 biasMatrix=mat4(
    
        .5,.0,.0,0.,
        .0,.5,.0,0.,
        .0,.0,.5,0.,
        .5,.5,.5,1.
        
   );

    mat4 rotationMatrix(vec3 axis_,float angle_) {

        axis_=normalize(axis_);
        float s=sin(angle_);
        float c=cos(angle_);
        float oc=1.0-c;

        return mat4(oc*axis_.x*axis_.x+c,oc*axis_.x*axis_.y-axis_.z*s,oc*axis_.z*axis_.x+axis_.y*s,0.0,oc*axis_.x*axis_.y+axis_.z*s,oc*axis_.y*axis_.y+c,oc*axis_.y*axis_.z-axis_.x*s,0.0,oc*axis_.z*axis_.x-axis_.y*s, oc*axis_.y*axis_.z+axis_.x*s, oc*axis_.z*axis_.z+c,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
                    
    }

    float parabola(float x_,float k_) {  return pow(4.*x_*(1.-x_),k_); }

    mat3 calcLookAtMatrix(vec3 origin_,vec3 target_,float roll_) {
    
        vec3 rr=vec3(sin(roll_),cos(roll_),0.0);
        vec3 ww=normalize(target_-origin_);
        vec3 uu=normalize(cross(ww,rr));
        vec3 vv=normalize(cross(uu,ww));

        return mat3(uu,vv,ww);
        
    }

    void main() {

        vec2 dimensions=vec2(width,height);

        float px=position.y;
        float vi=position.z;
        float x=mod(px,dimensions.x);
        float y=mod(floor(px/dimensions.x),dimensions.y);
        vec2 uv=vec2(x,y)/dimensions;

        vec4 cubePosition=texture2D(map,uv);
        vec4 prevPosition=texture2D(prevMap,uv);
        float alpha=cubePosition.a/100.;
        float scale=.025*parabola(1.-alpha,1.);
        vec3 faceNormal=boxNormals[ int(vi/6.) ];
        mat4 localRotation=mat4(calcLookAtMatrix(cubePosition.xyz,prevPosition.xyz,0.));

        vec4 rotatedNormal=localRotation*vec4(faceNormal,1.);
        vec3 visPosition=(modelMatrix*(cubePosition+rotatedNormal*scale)).xyz;
        float d=dot(normalize(visPosition-cameraPosition),normalize((modelMatrix*rotatedNormal).xyz));
        vec3 boxVertex=boxVertices[ int(vi+(1.-step(0.,d))*50.) ];
        vec3 modifiedVertex=vec3((localRotation*vec4(boxVertex*scale*boxScale*meshScale,1.)).xyz);
        vec3 modifiedPosition=cubePosition.xyz+modifiedVertex;

        gl_Position=projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vec4(modifiedPosition,1.0);
        vPosition=modifiedPosition;

        vShadowCoord=biasMatrix*shadowP*shadowV*modelMatrix*vec4(modifiedPosition,1.);

        vColor=texture2D(diffuse,uv);
        vLightPosition=lightPosition;

    }

    </script>

    <script id="fs-particles" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    
    #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable

    precision highp float;

    uniform float spread;

    varying vec3 vPosition;
    varying vec4 vColor;

    varying vec4 vShadowCoord;
    uniform sampler2D depthTexture;
    uniform sampler2D projector;
    varying vec3 vLightPosition;
    uniform vec2 resolution;
    uniform sampler2D blob;

    float bias;

    float unpackDepth(const in vec4 rgba_depth_) {

        const vec4 bit_shift=vec4(1.0/(256.0*256.0*256.0),1.0/(256.0*256.0),1.0/256.0,1.0);
        return dot(rgba_depth_,bit_shift);

    }

    float random(vec4 seed4_){
    
        float dot_product=dot(seed4_,vec4(12.9898,78.233,45.164,94.673));
        return fract(sin(dot_product)*43758.5453);
        
    }

    float sampleVisibility(vec3 coord_) { return step(coord_.z,unpackDepth(texture2D(depthTexture,coord_.xy+0.*(.5-random(vec4(coord_,bias)))/2048.))+bias); }

    mat2 rotationMatrix(float a_) { return mat2(cos(a_),sin(a_),-sin(a_),cos(a_)); }

    const float PI=3.14159265358979323846264;

    void main() {

        vec3 fdx=dFdx(vPosition);
        vec3 fdy=dFdy(vPosition);
        vec3 n=normalize(cross(fdx,fdy));

        vec4 base=vec4(1.);

        vec3 L=normalize(vLightPosition-vPosition);
        vec3 E=normalize(cameraPosition-vPosition);

        float diffuse=max(0.,dot(L,n));

        float theta=clamp(-diffuse,0.,1.);
        bias=0.005*tan(acos(theta));
        bias=clamp(bias,0.,0.01);

        float shadow=0.;
        vec3 shadowCoord=vShadowCoord.xyz/vShadowCoord.w;

        float step=spread;
        vec2 inc=vec2(step)/resolution;

        shadow += sampleVisibility(shadowCoord+vec3(    0.,-inc.y,0.));
        shadow += sampleVisibility(shadowCoord+vec3(-inc.x,    0.,0.));
        shadow += sampleVisibility(shadowCoord+vec3(    0.,    0.,0.));
        shadow += sampleVisibility(shadowCoord+vec3( inc.x,    0.,0.));
        shadow += sampleVisibility(shadowCoord+vec3(    0., inc.y,0.));
        shadow /= 5.;

        vec4 mask=texture2D(projector,vShadowCoord.xy);

        float shininess=2.;
        vec3 halfVector=normalize(E+L);
        float specular=dot(n,halfVector)*.5;
        specular=max(0.0,specular);
        specular=pow(specular,shininess);

        float ambient=1.;
        float o=diffuse*shadow*mask.r;
        vec3 color=mix(vColor.rgb,vec3(1.),.8*clamp(-n.y,0.,1.));
        vec3 diffuseColor=color*mix(vec3(o),vec3(1.),ambient);
        vec3 specularColor=vec3(1.);

        base.rgb=mix(diffuseColor,specularColor,specular*o);

        gl_FragColor=base;

    }

    </script>

    <script id="fs-particles-shadow" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    precision highp float;

    vec4 packDepth(const in float depth_) {
    
        const vec4 bit_shift=vec4(256.0*256.0*256.0,256.0*256.0,256.0,1.0);
        const vec4 bit_mask =vec4(0.0,1.0/256.0,1.0/256.0,1.0/256.0);
        vec4 res=mod(depth_*bit_shift*vec4(255),vec4(256))/vec4(255);
        res -= res.xxyz*bit_mask;
        return res;
    }

    void main() {

        gl_FragColor=vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);

    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

I have attached tweaked version here as snippet. Had to compress JS to fit 30.000 limits.

Answer (score 1):

I have cut all polygon boxes shaders, which have 18 vertices per box and replaced them by simple THREE.Points() geometry with just one vertex.

The demo is published on bl.ocks.org, since it's over 30.000 StackOverflow limits.

https://bl.ocks.org/vkuchinov/56aebc7ef741ea6a544c36a22e572d54